# Is it possible to launch a QR Code scan from a mobile web app running on iPad?

Tags: ipad, qr-code

Client wants a button on the mobile web app that launches a QR code scan (with camera on iPad) then returns to the mobile web app with the QR code info. Wondering how best to achieve this and/or if it's even possible. Thanks!

Comment: I just came across phonegap.com, which seems to allow access to native features like camera from webapps. Does anyone know if that would work?

Comment: Seems that access to the camera needs a native app. Choices seem to be some kind of native wrapper for the web app aka Adobe Phonegap/Cordova or using a URL scheme to launch a native app then pass the info back aka zxing. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see the `zxing:` URL format [here](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-From-Web-Pages).

Comment: How would you accomplish this *without* an external app ceejayoz? That's not a condition of the question because it can't be. The question wonders if it's even possible, and it is. Your answer of 'not possible' isn't correct.

Comment: If it's supposed to work reliably, it's not possible. Telling users they need a particular application for it to work is going to be bad user experience, and a short URL (bit.ly/something) would probably be a hundred times better. Sometimes, the answer to "can I drive a car from the US to England" is "no", not "if you add floats and a propeller and pray maybe".

Comment: Perfect for someone like me who has control over the users and their phones (working on a project internally for an office). Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this feature is no longer active.

Comment: I'd delete this because the iOS app that provides this is long since unmaintained, but can't as it's the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Not really possible, sorry.

The closest you can get is some apps have a URL scheme (`redlaser://`, for example) that you could provide a link to. There's no way of detecting that they've got the app installed, though.

Comment: +1 for mentioning a working url scheme, though the app crashes when I test it on my dev phone. (iOS 6 Beta)

Comment: This is much closer to what should be an accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

The best thing would be to use a bluetooth barcode scanner. Something like Socket scan , CX2864-1336 would work for well for this. I've seen it used with an ipad to manage inventory.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that would require two separate native applications. Both using URL schemes to jump to the other and pass information. If you have a web app and check for a QR code scanner's URL scheme it's totally possible for your web app to launch a QR code scan but passing data back would require a native app. Oh, and I'm not sure if there are any QR code apps with a scheme.