# Creating a link in a mobile website that will open a QR code scanner

Tags: android, iphone, jquery-mobile, qr-code

It is possible to create a link in a mobile website that will open a QR code scanner on an iPhone or Android phone when the user clicks on it?

Specifically, I am building a site using jQuery Mobile and want to have a button that says "Scan QR Code." When the clicks on it, it will open whatever scanning app they have on their phone.

I found [another similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195178/is-it-possible-to-launch-a-qr-code-scan-from-a-mobile-web-app-running-on-ipad), and it appears the answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help you:

http://qrdroid.com/web-masters.php

Create a link like this one:
http://qrdroid.com/scan?q=http://www.example.com/your_page?q={CODE}

The scanner will be launched. After the user scans a code, your webpage will be opened with the scanned code as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

On Android at least you can request the developers of the QR Scanner apps to add an Intent Filter for the URL you send the user to on click, which will then launch their app. Note that the user will still be prompted to choose between the QR Scanner and the browser(s) on the device, and there is nothing you can do about that.